# How to fix cd command does not work in Kali Linux

Tags: linux

This is what happens when i type cd.

```
kali@kali:~$ cd
kali@kali:~$
```

Nothing pops out

```
kali@kali:~$ cd
kali@kali:~$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
kali@kali:~$ pwd
/home/kali
kali@kali:~$ cd Desktop
kali@kali:~/Desktop$ cd
kali@kali:~$
```

still nothing

Comment: you can find more information about the cd command here: https://linuxize.com/post/linux-cd-command/

Comment: A lot unix commands will not display anything if they worked succesfully. cd is one of them

Answer (score 0):

Without arguments, `cd` changes directory to your $`HOME` directory.

If you look to your output, something has changed. You were in directory Desktop `kali@kali:~/Desktop$` and after `cd`, the shell changed the directory to `~` (`kali@kali:~$`) which is the `$HOME` directory of the current user.

By default if the `cd` command executes with success no output is displayed and the directory is changed, but if you try to change to some directory that does not exist an error message will be output.

For instance, assuming you don't have directory `abc` in your root, doing the following in a bash shell will output an error:

```
$ cd /abd
bash: cd: /abd: No such file or directory
```

Comment: In some cases it's also possible that `PS1` is hardcoded instead of set to `\w` and it never changes

Answer (score 0):

In the newest versions of Kali anyway (2020+), there is no cd command. Simply type the directory name (e.g. Downloads -no slashes brackets or flags at all), this is why nothing happens. I've only done this from root but I expect it works the same from a regular user account as well.

Comment: Hi Jerry, you can improve your answer by providing more details and examples, please have a look at How to give awesome answers from here :https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer